# Best way to replace <a><li></li></a>?

Tags: html, button, navigation, html-lists

I'm writing a web page at the moment and have just validated it- the W3C validator doesn't like this:

```
<nav id="footNav">
    <ul>
            <a href="contact.html"><li>Contact</li></a>
            <a href="access.html"><li>Accessibility</li></a><br>
            <li>&copy; A dev, 2015</li>
    </ul>
<nav id="footNav">
```

As the links are outside the list elements. I can accept that that's the wrong way to do it, but what should I replace it with? The effect I'm going for is that of 'buttons'- i.e. you don't have to click the text, you can click anywhere in the general (padded) area of the link.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's an invalid markup. The `ul` element can only have `li` children. You can swap the `a` elements with the list elements and use the `display: block` rule in your CSS. Now the `a` elements are *block* elements that take all the available space.

```
<style>
#footNav li a {
  display: block;
}
</style>
<nav id="footNav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="access.html">Accessibility</a></li>
        <li>&copy; A dev, 2015</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very much!